# Reference all indexes in list and check for existence of value in python

Tags: python, json, list

I'm trying to create `if` block in my python3 script that checks if a value exists within a list I pull from JSON. The JSON data is below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 59616405645,
    "name": "Foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 990164054345,
    "name": "FindMe"
  },
  {
    "id": 2009167874,
    "name": "Bar"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to determine whether or not the value of `Bar` exists within the list. To do so I'm doing the following which directly references the index:

```
if "FindMe" in m_orgs[1].values():
    print("Yo it's here")
else:
    print("Yo it's not here.")
```

But the JSON data I'm pulling will always have different results and we will never know the index numbers, so direct reference will not work. How do I reference all indexes in a list at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference all indexes at once, but you can loop through them, and stop as soon as you find the first existence. Something like:

```
found = any("findMe" in item.values() for item in m_orgs)
```

This line will stop the execution when it finds the first `True` value. So worst case, it will look through every position and not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) like this:

```
if any(d['name'] == 'Foo' for d in json):
    do this
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, sorry, I didn't get you, I changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can first translate the original json data to set of data, and then simply check through set operations,

```
name_set = {org['name'] for org in m_orgs}
print 'FindMe' in name_set
```